# Is this the correct way to avoid the ServiceLocator pattern, by using Constructor Injection?

Tags: dependency-injection, mef, service-locator, common-service-locator

Is this the correct way to avoid the ServiceLocator pattern, by using Constructor Injection?

```
public interface IEntitySomethingBase<TEntity>
{
    //Stuff
}

public class AccountEntitySomething : IEntitySomethingBase<Account>
{
    //Stuff
}

public class CustomerEntitySomething : IEntitySomethingBase<Customer>
{
    //Stuff
}

public class OrderEntitySomething : IEntitySomethingBase<Order>
{
    //Stuff
}
//Ditto, any number
```

Consuming Class using the ServiceLocator that I want to avoid.

```
public class MyConsumingClass
{
    public object DoSomething<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var thing = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEntitySomethingBase<TEntity>>();
    }
}
```

Solution using MEF. Modify above *EntitySomething's to Export, and

```
public class MyConsumingClass
{
    private List<Lazy<IEntitySomethingBase<Object>>> _things;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MyConsumingClass([ImportMany] List<Lazy<IEntitySomethingBase<Object>>> things)
    {
        _things = things;
    }

    public object DoSomething<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var thing = _things.Cast<IEntityInformationExtractor<TEntity>>().Where(t => t.GetType().FullName == entity.GetType().FullName).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Not actually tried it yet, but was wondering if there where other ways of achieving this.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct, you need a factory

What you are trying to achieve has actually become really usual, and that's because the IoC containers resolve dependencies when the application starts up, and in most of the applications the dependencies required need to be injected based on some constraints.

Moderns IoC containers try to address this, like Guice for Java

Read this to get more information about factories:

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki

What you need is a factory to create the correct type based on the parameter, and you can place a call to your service locator inside of your factory (I know you are using the service locator anti-pattern but you are moving it from your domain to the factory, a factory is only used to wire up objects so it's common to have calls to the IoC inside factories).

For reference:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEhu57pih5w&feature=player_embedded